# How do I solve 'UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library' in Ubuntu?

Tags: java

Everytime I try to run my Program I get this message. I already used the command `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` and installed it, but it still doesn`t work.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:277)
        at StdDraw.<clinit>(StdDraw.java:488)
        at Envelope.main(Envelope.java:11)
```

Comment: Clearly you've already installed openjdk 17 and now there's a conflict. Which jdk do you want?

Comment: I deleted openjdk 11, updated my ubuntu and then downloaded openjdk17 and now I can run my program.

Comment: Want to put that as a proper answer? Then others potentially can use your question and answer to solve their problems as well...